# Dynamic prepared insert statement with optional form fields

Tags: php, forms, prepared-statement

So I found this question/answer from a few years ago and it is similar to what I need but I don't think I am understanding it correctly. What happens if your `$_POST` field count and db field count are not the same due to optional fields in the form?

```
function insertToDB($params, $db) { //Pass array and db

    $fields = array();
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'db') or die('XXX');     
    $stmt =  $conn->stmt_init();
    $stmt->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$db); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $meta =  $stmt->result_metadata();
    while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) { 
         $fields[] = $field->name;   
    }

    $fields = implode(", ", $fields);


    $placeholders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($params), '?'));

    $types = '';
    foreach($params as $value) {
        $types.= substr(strtolower(gettype($value)), 0, 1); 
    }

    $ins = "INSERT INTO MYDB (".$fields.") VALUES (".$placeholders.")"; 

    $bind_names[] = $types; 
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($params); $i++) { 
        $bind_name = 'bind' . $i;
        $$bind_name = $params[$i];
        $bind_names[] = &$$bind_name;
    }
    if ($stmt->prepare($ins)) {
            call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_param'),$bind_names); 
            $insresult = $stmt->execute(); 
    }
    return $insresult;
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a field is optional then you should check if the $_POST is set you can do this like:

```
if(isset($_POST["fieldsection"])) {
$var = $_POST["fieldsection"];
} else {
$var = "Default Value"
}
```

That way the field count and mysql count can always be the same because it is seeing if there was a selection or not then if there wasn't it sets one for you.

Comment: So if it is an optional field, say a url for example and no url is entered `$var = "";` in the prepared statement it would look like `bind_param("ss", $_POST['somestr'],,$_POST['anotherstr'])` and that won't cause it to fail?

Comment: Firstly you have two ,, between the two posts. If it is a url field then make the default # which if you plan to use this as a link to something then it will just go to the top of the page.

Comment: Yes, there are 2 commas because if $var is empty it will still create a spot for it, won't it? With some fields it is okay to  be empty, that is why they are optional, but I also don't want default values all over the place either. Maybe I need to rethink this a bit.

Comment: of right. No in that case I am pretty sure you need to do this: bind_param("ss", $_POST['somestr'],$var,$_POST['anotherstr']) otherwise the $var wont show up.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a quick example, suppose you have these table fields

```
$table_fields = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
```

and you input data looks like this

```
$input_data = array('foo' => 1,
                    'bar' => 2);
```

What you can do is set some default input data for each of the table fields (I am lazy, so all defaulted to `NULL`)

```
array_fill(0, count($table_fields), NULL)
```

Then we zip them together with [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

```
array_combine($table_fields, array_fill(0, count($table_fields), NULL))
```

So that your input data can override the default values whenever possible with [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php), as follows

```
var_dump(
    array_merge(
        array_combine($table_fields, array_fill(0, count($table_fields), NULL)),
        $input_data
    )
);

# prints
# array(3) {
#  ["foo"]=>
#  int(1)
#  ["bar"]=>
#  int(2)
#  ["baz"]=>
#  NULL
#}
```

However, if possible, can you try making the optional fields really optional, such that in your `CREATE TABLE` statement make sure there's a default value set for those fields? In that case you will also save one round to the database to query for the field names (`$stmt->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$db);`, you probably can use `LIMIT 1` to speed it up if you really need that). So instead your this line

```
$ins = "INSERT INTO MYDB (".$fields.") VALUES (".$placeholders.")";
```

will become

```
$ins = "INSERT INTO MYDB (".implode(",", array_keys($params)).") VALUES (".$placeholders.")";
```